1 curly bracket on the left and 2 curly brackets on the right of a list of items
I feel the answer should be somewhat obvious, and yet it evades me. I am attaching a picture of what I need (7 items vertically ordered on different rows: item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item7, item7 and a left curly bracket spanning items 1-7 with a centered label Z, and a right curly bracket spanning items 1-4 with a label A and another right curly bracket spanning items 5-7 with a label B). I'm also attaching a sample code getting halfway there, it has a left and a right bracket spanning items 1-7. The question is how to produce 2 brackets on the right 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
X \left\{
\begin{gathered}
\text{item 1} \\
\text{item 2} \\
\text{item 3} \\
\text{item 4} \\
\text{item 5} \\
\text{item 6} \\
\text{item 7}
\end{gathered} \right\} Y
\end{equation*}

\end{document}

many thanks!!!

Similar to Sigur's answer, but without cases and instead using array:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  Z \left\{
    \begin{array}[c]{@{}l@{}}
      \!\left.
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
          item 1 \\
          item 2 \\
          item 3 \\
          item 4 \\
        \end{tabular}
      \right\} A
      \\
      \!\left.
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
          item 5 \\
          item 6 \\
          item 7 \\
        \end{tabular}
      \right\} B
    \end{array}
  \right.\!
\end{equation*}
\end{document}



Please, could explain the last \!?

@Sigur to correctly centre it. Every \left. and \right. adds a bit of padding that needs to get removed if it's not wanted.

Oh, I see... to center the whole equation contents... nice!

Thank you so much, please see my other answer, it's to both of you.

Like this?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
X 
\begin{cases}
\left.
\begin{tabular}{l}
item 1 \\
item 2 \\
item 3 \\
item 4
\end{tabular}
\right\} A \\
\left.
\begin{tabular}{l}
item 5 \\
item 6 \\
item 7
\end{tabular}
\right\} B
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}


Thank you both so so much! I wish I could buy you each a drink! I already spent a few hours with both chatgpt and gemini trying to answer this question and they are not able to do it. And you did it with your human intelligence in no time. I really really appreciate you both. I've never used equation before so I am in no position to decide between the two answers. I just thank you both. Hope this helps someone in the future too.

@vtheb, welcome to TEX.SE. One good way to learn TeX is to study the code produced by people here. IMHO I recommend not spend time with GPT. Search here and study the codes. Have a nice day.

Hi @vtheb and welcome from me as well. Just like Sigur said, don't bother with GPT or similar LLMs. In my experience they are only usable in fields in which you already have at least basic knowledge to filter out the hallucinations. Way too many people take what those AIs say them for granted or put too much trust in them. As to which answer to accept: Whichever you think looks better, or if in doubt the faster one. The basic idea is the same in both.

@vtheb, in addition to Skillmon comment, if you observe deeply there is bit difference in brace alignments in my solution. I'd choose the other to use because the perfect vertical alignment. But if you think my code is easier to study, don't worry. The important fact is to learn TeX and enjoy it.

Thank you both! I've been using basic LaTeX for papers and posters for 10 years and this is only the second time ever I could not find an answer to my q (never had to use equations before). LLMs were touted as great for code and it's interesting that you say "don't bother" because they just sent me running in circles for many many prompts. ChatGPT was never even able to understand the concept that one bracket spans 4 rows and the other only 3, it kept producing equally sized brackets on the right (with tikz!?!?), no matter how I rephrased it.

You can use nicematrix
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{NiceMatrix}
\Block{7-1}{Z} & \text{item 1} & \Block{4-1}{A}\\
& \text{item 2} \\
& \text{item 3} \\
& \text{item 4} \\
& \text{item 5} & \Block{3-1}{B} \\
& \text{item 6} \\
& \text{item 7} \\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix\{{1-2}{7-2}.
  \SubMatrix.{1-2}{4-2}\}
  \SubMatrix.{5-2}{7-2}\}
\end{NiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}


If you want some space around the items use NiceArray:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{NiceArray}{c>{\ }c<{\ }c}
\Block{7-1}{Z} & \text{item 1} & \Block{4-1}{A}\\
& \text{item 2} \\
& \text{item 3} \\
& \text{item 4} \\
& \text{item 5} & \Block{3-1}{B} \\
& \text{item 6} \\
& \text{item 7} \\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix\{{1-2}{7-2}.
  \SubMatrix.{1-2}{4-2}\}
  \SubMatrix.{5-2}{7-2}\}
\end{NiceArray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}


